# How to access an attribute of an object which is stored in arraylist?

Tags: java

```
String temp = sgDetails.get(0).sgShift;
```

In this we have an arraylist sgdetails that stores objects of guards with fields such as name, id, sal and so on. I am unable to access shift of object stored at first index of arraylist.

Comment: Give more details about the `sgDetails`, what is the type of ArrayList is that?

Comment: probably because it is proteced/private, see if the class has getter for it and use it otherwise you are not allowed to access it

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the access specifire of variable `sgShift` in class Guard is `public` or better way is to keep it private and write getter method to access the variable `sgShift` by below code :

```
  private String sgShift;

  public String getSgShift() {
        return sgShift;
    }

  String temp = sgDetails.get(0).getSgShift();
```

Comment: what if he doesnt have the method...

Comment: @paul.cioroianu yes correct updated answer

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access it like that, make sure the field is public and not package level(no access level specified) or private. Though, I would suggest you make getters and setters to retrieve and set the fields of a class.

you can read more about encapsulation [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access private properties of a class without public getter's you can use reflaction.